# Multiple checkbox values not inserted in MySQL column

Tags: php, mysql

I know this issue has been asked several times and I've tried the given solutions but none doesn't seem to work with my script. D: Anyone would be kind enough to enlighten me and what am I doing wrong?

Here's the portion of the HTML script:

```
<td class="tableBody">
    <input type="checkbox" name="category[]" value="Website" /> Website
    <input type="checkbox" name="category[]" value="Members" /> Members
    <input type="checkbox" name="category[]" value="Updates" /> Updates
    <input type="checkbox" name="category[]" value="Cons" /> Cons
    <input type="checkbox" name="category[]" value="Others" /> Others
</td>
```

And this is the portion of MySQL script:

```
$title = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($_POST['title']));
    $entry = $_POST['entry'];
    $cat = implode(",", $_POST['category']);

    date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Manila');
    $timestamp = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

    $entry = nl2br(htmlentities($entry, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));

    if (!get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
            $title = addslashes($title);
            $entry = addslashes($entry);
        }

    $insert = "INSERT INTO `blog` (`id`, `username`, `entry_id`, `title`, `entry`, `category`, `timestamp`) VALUES ('$id', '$name', '',  '$title', '$entry', '$cat', '$timestamp');";
```

The form is working fine, only that the categories are not inserted into the column.[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the type of `category` column in your table? What is the value of `$cat` if you print it?

Comment: datatype of `category` column must be varchar if it is `int`

Comment: it's varchar, not int @PathikVejani

Comment: check your query you don't remove ';' from second last

Comment: removing the ';' didn't do anything @ImBS

Comment: any error display while run a query? @Aki

Comment: now that you mention it, I receive a success message when posting the entry but getting this in error_log: "PHP Warning:  implode(): Invalid arguments passed" which is the $cat = implode(",", $_POST['category']); in the script @ImBS

Comment: first you print_r($_POST['category']); exit; what is output? you can get result in array?

Comment: it doesn't show anything @ImBS

Comment: hmm so your category value is not pass in form post. now make sure your category checkbox is in <form> or not

Comment: D: it's within the <form> and </form> @ImBS

Comment: can you provide full code of your html and php?

Comment: @ImBS here's the link: [link]http://802.ethelion.net/form.txt

Comment: i think your top foreach loop might be affect on below code so remove foreach loop and check it's working or not otherwise code is looks perfect

Comment: @ImBS it did work, however the username and user id is gone :) but I did some tweaks and it's working fine now. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: @Aki let's enjoy your code

Comment: You have to write an answer with the final solution (and then accept it) or accept one of the availables (to help future readers, that's as SO works!). Remember to update your post deleting the useless "solved" in the title and "edit" in the post.

Answer (score 1):

Could you try change this line to this basicly add (array)..

```
$cat = implode(",", (array)$_POST['category']);
```

If that's not works again look this; I add some lines Add these and look if there was a error or something like that. There could be database connection or database structure issue. You can see if there was a error. I tested it and it worked for me.

```
<?php
        $title = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($_POST['title']));
        $entry = $_POST['entry'];
        $cat = implode(",", $_POST['category']);
        echo $cat;
        date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Manila');
        $timestamp = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

        $entry = nl2br(htmlentities($entry, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));

        if (!get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
                $title = addslashes($title);
                $entry = addslashes($entry);
            }

            //I add these lines from here, to...
            $servername = "localhost";
            $username = "root";
            $password = "";
            $dbname = "code";

            // Create connection
            $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
            // Check connection
            if ($conn->connect_error) {
                die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
            } 

            $sql = "INSERT INTO `blog` (`id`, `username`, `entry_id`, `title`, `entry`, `category`, `timestamp`) VALUES ('$id', '$name', '',  '$title', '$entry', '$cat', '$timestamp');";

            if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
                echo "New record inserted successfully";
            } else {
                echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
            }

            $conn->close();

            //Here...
    ?>
```

Comment: Hi, I also tried the basic array and nothing happened. As for the connection, it already has, otherwise it won't insert the other fields in mysql. Thank you :)

Comment: so there could be issue in your form can you share your form?

Answer (score 1):

As per ImBS' suggestion, I've removed the original foreach loop by putting it within a comment (for future reference) since it does affect the array for categories, and did some tweaks by moving the SQL data below it and it works fine now. :)

```
if (!isset($_POST['submit']) || $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] != "POST") {
    exit("<p>You did not press the submit button; this page should not be accessed directly.</p>");
}
else {

$exploits = "/(content-type|bcc:|cc:|document.cookie|onclick|onload|javascript|alert)/i";
$profanity = "/(beastial|bestial|blowjob|clit|cum|cunilingus|cunillingus|cunnilingus|cunt|ejaculate|fag|felatio|fellatio|fuck|fuk|fuks|gangbang|gangbanged|gangbangs|hotsex|jism|jiz|kock|kondum|kum|kunilingus|orgasim|orgasims|orgasm|orgasms|phonesex|phuk|phuq|porn|pussies|pussy|spunk|xxx)/i";
$spamwords = "/(viagra|phentermine|tramadol|adipex|advai|alprazolam|ambien|ambian|amoxicillin|antivert|blackjack|backgammon|texas|holdem|carisoprodol|ciara|ciprofloxacin|debt|dating|porn)/i";
$bots = "/(Indy|Blaiz|Java|libwww-perl|Python|OutfoxBot|User-Agent|PycURL|AlphaServer)/i";

if (preg_match($bots, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])) {
    exit("<h1>Error</h1>\nKnown spam bots are not allowed.<br /><br />");
}
/* FOREACH LOOP
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    $value = trim($value);

    if (preg_match($exploits, $value)) {
        exit("<h1>Error</h1>\nExploits/malicious scripting attributes aren't allowed.<br /><br />");
    }
    elseif (preg_match($profanity, $value) || preg_match($spamwords, $value)) {
        exit("<h1>Error</h1>\nThat kind of language is not allowed through our form.<br /><br />");
    }

    $_POST[$key] = stripslashes(strip_tags($value));
}
END FOREACH LOOP */

    $connect = mysqli_connect("$db_server", "$db_user", "$db_password", "$db_database");
    $select=mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM `$table_members` WHERE username='$_SESSION[logged_in]'");
            while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($select)) {
                $id = $row['id'];
                $name = $row['username'];
            }

    $title = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($_POST['title']));
    $entry = $_POST['entry'];
    $category = $_POST['category'];
    $cat = implode(", ", $_POST['category']);

    date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Manila');
    $timestamp = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

    $entry = nl2br(htmlentities($entry, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));

    if (!get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
            $title = addslashes($title);
            $entry = addslashes($entry);
    }

    $insert = "INSERT INTO `blog` (`id`, `username`, `entry_id`, `title`, `entry`, `category`, `timestamp`) VALUES ('$id', '$name', '',  '$title', '$entry', '$cat', '$timestamp')";

    if(mysqli_query($connect, $insert)) {
        echo '<h1>Success!</h1>
        You have successfully posted a new blog entry!';
    }
    else {
        echo '<h1>Error</h1>
        It looks like there was an error in processing your submitted form.';   
    }
}
```

Thank you for all the suggestions! :)

Answer (score 0):

Everything seems to be fine except your datatype of category. Its may not be varchar. Try to use varchar. Your query could be showing some warning, use

`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

to on error reporting then solve query manually.